# Decompiling PYC file with Uncompyle6 getting AssertionError

Tags: python

I am trying to recover the original python scripts from a pyinstaller exe. I was able to extract the files from the exe and obtain the magic number. From what I read, the main .py file (found in the extract folder with no suffix) just needs to be renamed to main.pyc and the magic number appended should work. I followed these instructions and it worked, but my issue is the other .pyc files (found in the PYZ-00.pyz_extracted) all error out when I try to decompile them with uncompyle6 - even when I append the magic number. The error I'm getting is:

Unknown type 0

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main

```
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
```

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code

```
exec(code, run_globals)
```

File "C:\Users\hahenry\Anaconda3\Scripts\uncompyle6.exe_*main*_.py", line 7, in

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\bin\uncompile.py", line 193, in main_bin

```
result = main(src_base, out_base, pyc_paths, source_paths, outfile,
```

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\main.py", line 316, in main

```
deparsed = decompile_file(
```

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\main.py", line 208, in decompile_file

```
decompile(
```

File "c:\users\hahenry\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\main.py", line 83, in decompile

```
assert iscode(co)
```

AssertionError